# Selecting multiple counts

Tags: mysql, database

For my homework I get a database that has to do with cars.
Tables:
autos: chassisnr, autoinfo_id, verkopers_id
verkopers: id, naam, adres, provincie
autoinfo: id, merk, model, bouwjaar, brandstof, prijs

Sorry but the database is written in Dutch so can't really translate it to English.
I need to select the number of cars that each seller has sold and order it by the amount of cars sold. There are 4 sellers: Bram, Katja, Kristien and Peter

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(WHERE naam LIKE 'Katja') AS COUNT_KATJA,
       COUNT(WHERE naam LIKE 'Bram') AS COUNT_BRAM,
       COUNT(WHERE naam LIKE 'Kristien') AS COUNT_KRISTIEN,
       COUNT(WHERE naam LIKE 'Peter') AS COUNT_PETER,
       merk, model
       FROM verkopers, autoinfo
ORDER BY COUNT
```

What seems to be wrong?
Thanks for the effort and sorry for any inconvenience (my first question)
PS: this is my first time working with a database hence the lack of experience, possibly a very easy answer, can't seem to find it in my textbook about MySQL

Kind regards

Joachim

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY` and `JOIN`.

Comment: Please review the answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT v.naam, COUNT(a.autoinfo_id) AS numSold
FROM autos a INNER JOIN verkopers v
    ON a.verkopers_id = v.id
WHERE v.naam IN ('Bram', 'Katja', 'Kristien', 'Peter')
GROUP BY v.naam
ORDER BY COUNT(a.autoinfo_id) DESC
```

Comment: hey! thanks for the answer, I've posted a link to the exact database design, cuz I just can't seem to get it working, http://prntscr.com/aqht4u

Comment: Sorry about that, this is my first time asking a question :) sorry if I have offended you in any way

Comment: No worries.  Clean up your image, upright it, and update your original question.